# Why is my GA4 Custom Event not triggering if the reference event is triggered from GTM?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I've been having issues with GA4 not triggering custom events as I would expect it to. Basically I have a GTM tag that triggers an event with `event_name: purchase` along with a series of fields, `item_type` being one of them. The tag triggers correctly and it sends the purchase event over to GA4 as it should.

Now, I have a secondary GA4 event `bundle_purchase`. This one is configured via GA4 such that it is triggered once a `purchase` event (condition: event_name equals purchase) is triggered with an item_type containing bundle (condition: item type contains (ignore case) bundle).

The problem is so far this second event has not triggered once even though I've waited almost a week for it to do so and I've been doing manual triggers myself.

Does anyone know what could be wrong and / or if I am using the setup incorrectly?

So far I've tried:

- Triggering the GTM tag by hand
- Waiting over 48 hours for the secondary event to show up
- Changing the trigger conditions for the secondary event

Comment: you should provide more info about the events, tag and triggers, dimensions etc. how can we respond if we do not know what exactly you have done. 
what do you mean by triggering GTM tag by hand?